# How to got verify DNS record in Godaddy# by Amazon Web Service#?

Tags: amazon-web-services, godaddy-api

I want to send email using AWS Simple Email Service from my domain email address, but during configuration, finding verification issue by AWS.

1) I have purchase domain from GoDaddy and create email with that domain.
2) Register my domain in AWS portal.
2) To enable email serviice, AWS provided me TXT and CNAME record, which were supposed to be set in DNS record in GoDaddy Portal. I hhave done that setup.
3) AWS supposed to verify those record fron DNS setting but it is not able to verify.

Please help, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: A common error is to enter the provided value `some-string.example.com` instead of just using `some-string` as the hostname, when creating the desired record.  This results in the actual record being created as `some-string.example.com.example.com` which will not work.  Check this?

Answer (score 1):

Just for better visibility, @michael-sqlbot's answer is working.

If you have `put-this-into-host.your-domain.com` then just use `put-this-into-host`, because the domain will automatically be suffixed.